# Secure hash generation for passwords

Tags: php, hash, passwords, crypt

Is it possible to get password from hash produced by following function by any method?

`$salt` is random 128 characters alpha numeric string.

```
function Get_Hash($pwd, $salt)
        {
            if ( CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1) 
            {
                $pwd = hash("sha512",$pwd);
                $cost = "07";
                $hash = crypt($pwd, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt);
                return $hash;
            } 
            else  
            {
                $pwd = hash("sha512",$pwd);
                $hash = crypt($pwd, '$1$' . $salt . '$');
                return $hash;
            }
        }
```

There is already basic level brute force protection, system locked for 3-5 minutes after 3 failed attempts.

Is this good hashing function for small level application?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create your own hashing.

PHP version 5.5 has some [very nice and easy to use password hashing functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php), and there is a library that backports them as far as to PHP 5.3.

Include it, use it. Done.

Download here https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat or include via Composer:

```
"require":{
    "ircmaxell/password-compat":"~1.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look into password_compact, as I am using 5.4

Comment: just used password_compact and works flawlessly.